# Microsoft.Unity does not Unity.Resolve<ILogger> when my concrete class has two constructors?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, unity-container

I have a concrete class of `logger` that Microsoft.Unity will resolve `ILogger` to.

The logger class has two constructors:

```
1. public logger()
2. public logger(List<BaseLogger> Loggers)
```

I have the unity section in my web.config file that looks like this:

```
<unity>
<containers>
  <container>
    <types>

      <type type="MyCompany.Logger.ILogger, MyCompany.Logger"
           mapTo="MyCompany.Logger.logger, MyCompany.Logger">

      </type>
    </types>
   </container>
  </containers>
</unity>
```

If I remove the constructor listed as 2, the logger class is successfully resolved by Unity. When I add it back I get this error...

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MyCompany.Logger.ILogger", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>   Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type List`1 has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate.

Can anyone explain how I can change my web.config entry to handle having the "2." listed overloaded constructor in logger to work while trying to Unity.Resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity by default tries to create an instance using the constructor with the maximum number of parameters.

In order to specify which one to use, you need to make use of constructor injection. You can either mark the constructor to be used with `InjectionConstructor` attribute or specify the constructor in the configuration. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648441.aspx) should help.

I understand the documentation on MSDN isn't good enough. See [this](http://mint.litemedia.se/2009/05/25/part-2-dependency-injection-with-unity-and-xml-configuration/) if it helps. I am not able to find the link to the article I had read today at the office. That had quite good description. Good luck if you can find that one or a better one.

Comment: I see from the document you linked me to how to handle a simple type like a string for putting parameters in a web.config file.  What I am now having trouble seeing from the documentation is how do this with a more complex type like the List<BaseLogger> that I mentioned.